# Improper Integral $\int_0^\infty e^{x(t-\lambda)}dx$

Tags: calculus

How to solve this: $\int_0^\infty e^{x(t-\lambda)}dx$

Why do we have to assume $t<\lambda$. Can someone please explain me this?

Thanks!

edit: please no hate, I just asked the intuition behind, not the calculations :)

Comment: If $t>\lambda$ the integral diverges.

Comment: Just do the calculations...

Comment: @TheGeekGreek I did the calculations...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $t \geqslant \lambda,$ we have $t-\lambda \geqslant 0.$ For $0 \leqslant x<\infty,$ this implies $ (t-\lambda)x  \geqslant 0,$ so $\exp \left( (t-\lambda)x \right) \geqslant 1.$ Finally, this implies $\int_0^\infty \exp \left( (t-\lambda)x \right) dx \geqslant \int_0^\infty 1 dx=\infty,$ so the integral cannot converge.

Comment: Thanks @user!!!

Answer (score 3):

If $t >  \lambda$ the integrand is increasing, so there is no hope for the improper integral to be defined.
You could convince yourself by comparing (explicitly calculating) $\int_0 ^{\infty} e^{-x} \mathrm{d}x$ to $\int_0 ^{\infty} e^{x} \mathrm{d}x$

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_0^\infty e^{x(t-\lambda)}dx=\\\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{e^{x(t-\lambda)}}{(t-\lambda)}-\frac{e^{x(t-\lambda)}}{(t-\lambda)}|_{x=0}\\
\lim_{x\to \infty}\underbrace{\frac{e^{\color{red}{-\infty}}}{(t-\lambda)}}_{\color{red}{t-\lambda<0}}-\frac{e^{0(t-\lambda)}}{(t-\lambda)}\\=0-\frac{1}{t-\lambda}$$